# htacess mod_rewrite regex - include numbers but exclude letters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, regex-lookarounds

I have always struggled with regex, and after reading up on it for 45 mins my head is spinning. Negative lookaheads, what the...? (?:/(?:(?!s\d+).)*)+$<--- OMG!!!

:(

So, I have a rule

```
RewriteRule /([0-9]+) /?id=$1 [R]
```

and it works fine when the url is `www.hi.com/123`

How can I make it refresh to `/` (the document root i nthis case) if the url is `www.hi.com/123abc` or `www.hi.com/a123bc`?

I just want to make sure **only urls with numbers and nothing else** are matched.

I tried

```
RewriteRule /([0-9]+)([^a-z]+) /map.htm?marker=$1 [R]
```

But that refreshes to`www.hi.com/?id=404`, oddly enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match 1 or more numbers in regex it will be:

```
[0-9]+
```

To match 1 or more numbers or letters in regex it will be:

```
[0-9a-zA-z]+
```

For your case RewriteRule rule will be:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/?$ /map.htm?marker=$1 [NC,L,R=302]
```

which will match `/123abc` OR `/123abc/` OR `/123` OR `/abc/`, note that trailing slash is optional. Flags I used are:

```
NC    - Ignore Case
L     - Last
R=301 - Use http status 302 for resulting URL
```

#### I would strongly suggest you reading mod_rewrite Reference doc: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

However you also asked:

> How can I make it refresh to / (the document root i nthis case) if the
>   url is www.hi.com/123abc or www.hi.com/a123bc?

That rule would be:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/?$ / [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: thank you for the very detailed answer. I did look over documentation before posting because I agree that you should not post without first trying to solve things yourself. But your suggested soultion causes a loop, since the redirect is a new url, which of course also matches the [0-9a-z] -- also waht's the `/?` do at the end?

Comment: `/?` is for making trailing slash optional. I had tested this rule before posting my answer and it didn't cause any looping. If you look at the rule it matches `[0-9a-z]+` followed by optional `/`. On RHS URI is `map.htm` which won't match `[0-9a-z]+` because of presence of dot in it.